# Why do apps from the Microsoft store not require admin permission to install?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I noticed today when installing an app from the Microsoft store on my computer running Windows 10 that the app did not need administrator permission to install.

Normally when installing apps/programs from downloaded executables or installers the UAC window pops up to request my admin password before it is allowed to proceed. Even program updates often involve the UAC pop-up. I prefer things this way since my computer is occasionally used by people who I trust enough to use it, but not enough to install things or change important settings.

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/1048313/684581) covers how to prevent users from installing apps from the store, but that's not what I'm wondering.

What is different about installing an app from the Microsoft store versus other methods that allows the app to install without admin permission? Is it that the installation process is different for those apps, or does the Store itself has special permissions?

Comment: A Windows Store app has limitations on what it is permitted to do, so there is no need to ask user for UAC confirmation. Unless Microsoft has made some major blunder, any Windows Store app is "safe" to install. For example, an app from elsewhere could potentially erase all your personal files. A Windows Store app cannot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Normally when installing apps/programs from downloaded executables or
>   installers the UAC window pops up to request my admin password before
>   it is allowed to proceed. Even program updates often involve the UAC
>   pop-up.

The group policy that defines this behavior only applies to legacy desktop applications.

> Even program updates often involve the UAC pop-up. I prefer things
>   this way since my computer is occasionally used by people who I trust
>   enough to use it, but not enough to install things or change important
>   settings.

This is only true if the process requires permissions the user does not already have.  Even installing legacy desktop applications can be granted to a user within the User usergroup.

> What is different about installing an app from the Microsoft store
>   versus other methods that allows the app to install without admin
>   permission?

Universal Windows Programs (UWP) are sandboxed.  The permission to install and remove these programs are handled by a different group policy.

> Is it that the installation process is different for those apps, or
>   does the Store itself has special permissions?

The ability to launch Windows Store, install/remove UWP already installed on the system, is indeed its own permission seperate from your ability to install a legacy desktop WIN32 application.

Comment: As the question did not request the specific information on how to allow/deny the ability to remove UWP applications my answer does not contain that information.  As the question did not request information on the specific group policies for both legacy desktop application nor UWP I didn't mention them.  *Both of those seem to be candidates for their own question and answer.*

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that UWP apps are installed on a per user basis rather than system wide, hence are another reason we don't get a warning dialogue.

Comment: [More info on the Sandboxing in regards to File and Folder access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).  Shows that the Store Apps can't access anything that would require Admin access even if they wanted to, hence no reason to ever ask for Admin access.  Same goes for the registry -- Store Apps are not allowed to access the registry, period.

Comment: Last point UWP =/= Store App. You can write a UWP app that accesses things like files and the registry (i.e. by using interop and the Win32 API, and/or IPC, etc.), but it won't be allowed into the official MS Store if you do that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/04/14/cheat-sheet-for-using-brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps/